# Change params in the middle of the URL

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to change the params `id` and `version` in the middle of my URL:

```
localhost:8080/parent/id/version/child
```

I'm doing this in the parent component:

```
 this.router.navigate(['../../', newId, newVersion], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

The problem is, it navigates to `localhost:8080/parent/newId/newVersion` but what I need is `localhost:8080/parent/newId/newVersion/child`.

I **cannot** simply do this:

```
this.router.navigate(['../../', newId, newVersion, 'child'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Because there are more children. I just want to keep the remaining URL after the params.

Can someone help me please?!

Comment: Did you check this: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#usage-1

Comment: Yes, I read it.. Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you please share how you managed to solve this?